# How to extract json data and output to csv using jq

Tags: json, jq, export-to-csv

My json array file is one long file and has many objects [{},{},{},{}], within each object I need the value for three keys: "STK_NUM":"1004251 ", "DLR_COST":40.32 , "RTL_AMT":9.99. How would I write the jq program to get the key names as headers in my csv file: STK_NUM, DLR_COST,RTL_AMT and the values of these keys from all objects: 1004251,40.32,9.99 ? These three keys are in every object.

Desired csv:

```
STK_NUM,DLR_COST,RTL_AMT
1004251,40.32,9.99
1012658,29.99,4.69
1232556,18.89,2.49
```

I've tried:

```
jq -r .[].STK_NUM HSEitm.json
```

result:

```
"1004251"
"1012658"
"1232556"
```

All my other jq script attempts result in errors because I don't know what I'm doing.

If anyone could show me I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of DRY:

```
jq -r '
  ["STK_NUM", "DLR_COST", "RTL_AMT"] as $headers
  | $headers, 
    # Rows:
    map(.[$headers[]]) 
  | @csv
'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
jq -r '
  
  # Headers
  ["STK_NUM", "DLR_COST", "RTL_AMT"],
  
  # Rows
  (.[] | [.STK_NUM, .DLR_COST, .RTL_AMT])
  
  # Output Format
  | @csv
  
' HSEitm.json
```